# Kendo line chart - series name with labels in two rows

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, telerik, linechart, kendo-chart

I would like to know if it's possible to have line chart series names divided in two rows, with a label in addition (Group1 and Group2 from the photo). On the picture below you can see what I want to create.

If not, is it at least possible to divide series names in two rows (without labels)?

Here is the photo:
[image]

This is an example from a kendo ui homepage, here you can find the source code: [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/grouped-line-chart-different-markers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to play around with the **[legend width](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-legend.width)** and the **[legend item visual](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-legend.item.visual)**:

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/iGuMu)**

```
  legend: {
    position: "bottom",
    width: 360,
    item: {
      visual: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        var group = "";
        var rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect([0, 0], [140, 50]);
        if (e.series.name == "1. GOOG (close)"){
          group = "Group 1: ";
          rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect([0, 0], [200, 50]);
        } else if (e.series.name == "3. AMZN (close)"){
          group = "Group 2: ";
          rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect([0, 0], [200, 50]);
        }
        var color = e.options.markers.background;
        var labelColor = e.options.labels.color;

        var layout = new kendo.drawing.Layout(rect, {
          spacing: 5,
          alignItems: "center"
        });

         var grplabel = new kendo.drawing.Text(group, [0, 0], {
          fill: {
            color: "#000"
          }
        });

        var marker = new kendo.drawing.Path({
          fill: {
            color: color
          },
          stroke : {
            color: color
          }
        }).moveTo(10, 0).lineTo(10, 10).lineTo(0, 10).lineTo(0, 0).close();

        var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.series.name, [0, 0], {
          fill: {
            color: labelColor
          }
        });

        layout.append(grplabel, marker, label);
        layout.reflow()

        return layout;
      }
    }
  },
```

In the demo, I am checking the series name and adding the group label to the first and third series.  The the legend width is set so that it wraps to a second line. **NOTE: there is some trial and error to make this work with your data...**

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave me a useful example, I will make it work with my code somehow.